# In nested list find list has largest sum sum of values

Tags: python, list

I have nested list and I am trying to find out better approach to find list has largest sum of values.

Below is my nested list:

```
nums = [[[1, 3000], [1, 2000]],
        [[1, 3000], [2, 3000]],
        [[1, 3000], [3, 4000]],
        [[2, 5000], [1, 2000]],
        [[2, 5000], [2, 3000]],
        [[2, 5000], [3, 4000]],
        [[3, 4000], [1, 2000]],
        [[3, 4000], [2, 3000]],
        [[3, 4000], [3, 4000]]]
```

Desired output  = `[[2, 5000], [3, 4000]]` since sum of values largest.

My approach:

```
largest = []
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
  if (nums[i][0][1] + nums[i][1][1]) > (nums[i+1][0][1] + nums[i+1][1][1]):
    largest.append(nums[i])
print(largest)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `max` and a custom function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = max(nums, key=lambda x: sum(map(itemgetter(1), x)))

[[2, 5000], [3, 4000]]
```

Comment: this is really good approach, but still didnt get my head wrap around, on argument "1" itemgetter() takes

Comment: @mtkilic, argument `1` simply means sum index 1 (i.e. 2nd value, since Python is 0-indexed) from each of the 2 inner lists, for each outer sublist.

Answer (score 4):

```
DATA = [
    [[1, 3000], [1, 2000]],
    [[1, 3000], [2, 3000]],
    [[1, 3000], [3, 4000]],
    [[2, 5000], [1, 2000]],
    [[2, 5000], [2, 3000]],
    [[2, 5000], [3, 4000]],
    [[3, 4000], [1, 2000]],
    [[3, 4000], [2, 3000]],
    [[3, 4000], [3, 4000]],
]

tups = [
    (sum(n for _, n in row), row)
    for row in DATA
]

mx = max(tups)
print(mx)                        # (9000, [[2, 5000], [3, 4000]])
print([xs[0] for xs in mx[1]])   # [2, 3]
```

Comment: Can't you feed a generator expression to `max`? The list creation seems unnecessary.

Comment: @jpp Sure (other answers cover that territory). This answer illustrates a different idea: creating a sortable/maxable data structure with the sums paired to the input rows – a handy technique in many situations.

Comment: Sure, I mean you only need to change `tups = [...]` to `tups = (...)`.

Comment: @FMc this is really unique, what is the short way to get [2,3]. My goal is after finding largest sum, get the keys

Answer (score 2):

Sort the elements using the sum as the key:

```
max(DATA, key=lambda x:x[0][1] + x[1][1])
#[[2, 5000], [3, 4000]]
```

*This is the fastest solution for the posted data.*

Comment: I wish I can accept more than one answer. I appreciate for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

One way is using:

```
max(nums, key=lambda x:sum(list(zip(*x))[1]))
#[[2, 5000], [3, 4000]]
```

Comment: I like the idea but the list creation is unnecessary for using `sum`. You can use `itertools.islice` to slice an iterator, or define this explicitly yourself.

Comment: For example: `max(nums, key=lambda x:sum(next(iter(islice(zip(*x), 1, 2)))))`. No list creation.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Transhuman's answer:

```
print max(nums, key=lambda l: sum(l[0] + l[1]))
```